# Can't pass string with spaces to ShellExecuteA in C

Tags: c, windows

I try to pass a file path to `ShellExecuteA`. It doesn't work when the path contain spaces. I pass the file path to another application of mine and then do something with the path.

test.exe:

```
delFp[200] = "del \"C:\\Users\\John Doe\\Documents\\Winsock\\Winsock\\x64\\Release\\test.exe\"";
    ShellExecuteA(
        NULL,
        NULL,
        "MyOtherApplication.exe",
        delFp,
        NULL,
        SW_SHOW);
```

This is whay I do in `MyOtherApplication.exe`:

```
if (strncmp(argv[1], "del", 3) == 0)
    {
        printf("Deleting origin...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        str_cut(argv[1], 0, 3);
        char del[200];
        strcat_s(del, 200, "del \"");
        strcat_s(del, 200, argv[1]);
        strcat_s(del, 200, "\"");
        system(del); // Delete test.exe (not this program but the other one)
    }
```

Comment: `strcat_s(del, 200, "del \"");` will fail, because at that point the contents of the array `del` is *indeterminate*. You haven't initialized `del` so it's not a null-terminated string which is required by `strcat`.

Comment: I suggest you skip the whole `strcat_s` bit, and instead just use `snprint` to format the string at once.

Comment: You can also simplify and get rid of the space problem by using `int remove(const char *filename);`

Comment: I get the same result with snprintf. And remove() also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @WeatherVane But how am I gonna get the path? in MyOtherApplication.exe

Comment: Have you tried to print the value of `argv[1]` to see what it really contains? And have you checked `argc` to see that it's equal to (or larger than) `2`? Perhaps print `argc` as well.

Comment: Yes, it prints: delC:\\Users\\John but I want to get printed everything

Comment: How is ShellExecute relevant in any way? The entire problem is in the program you start. You should edit your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- You did not post the definition of `str_cut`, but you only remove 3 bytes from the beginning of the string whereas you should also skip or remove the spaces between `del` and the argument.
- you should use `strcpy_s` to copy the first string to the destination array `del`. As this array is uninitialized, `strcat_s()` might not copy the string at the beginning.
- if the `argv[1]` string already contains double quotes, you should not add an extra set.

Try this:

```
    char *p = argv[1];
    if (strncmp(p, "del", 3) == 0 && isspace((unsigned char)p[3])) {
        printf("Deleting origin...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        p += 4;
        while (isspace((unsigned char)*p))
            p++;
        char del[200];
        if (*p == '"') {
            // no quotes needed
            strcpy_s(del, sizeof del, "del ");
            strcat_s(del, sizeof del, p);
        } else {
            strcpy_s(del, sizeof del, "del \"");
            strcat_s(del, sizeof del, p);
            strcat_s(del, sizeof del, "\"");
        }
        system(del);
    }
```

Note these remarks:

- you should use the `remove` function defined in `<stdio.h>` to remove the file, instead of running the shell.
- it might be impossible to remove an executable file that is currently running on some legacy systems.
- you should use `snprintf` to compose the command strings:

  ```
    int len;
    if (*p == '"') {
        // no quotes needed
        len = snprintf(del, sizeof del, "del %s", p);
    } else {
        len = snprintf(del, sizeof del, "del \"%s\"", p);
    }
    if (len >= (int)sizeof(del)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "filename too long: %s\n", p);
    } else {
        system(del);
    }
  ```